# Independence of Random Variables characterization

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

we are asked to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $\{a< X\le b\}$ and $\{c<Y\le d\}$ are independent sets. However we only have that $\{X\le b\}$ and $\{Y\le d\}$ are independent?

Do we work with compliments of $\{X>a\}$ and $\{Y>c\}$? and then the union of those sets are somehow independent?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$P(a<X\leq b\wedge c<Y\leq d)=P(X\leq b\wedge c<Y\leq d)-P(X\leq a\wedge c<Y\leq d)=$$$$\left[P(X\leq b\wedge Y\leq d)-P(X\leq b\wedge Y\leq c)\right]-\left[P(X\leq a\wedge Y\leq d)-P(X\leq a\wedge Y\leq c)\right]$$

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think that takes care of the converse direction at the same time since we have equality throughout the factorization. Does this readily imply that the singletons $\{X=a\}$ and $\{Y=b\}$ are independent too? since you can choose $a$ to arbitrarily close to $b$ and same with $c$ close to $d$.

Comment: Yes. Btw if two random variables $X,Y$ are independent then for *any pair* $A,B$ of Borel sets the events $\{X\in A\}$ and $\{Y\in B\}$ are independent. That is a *necessary* condition for independence of $X$ and $Y$. A *sufficient* condition is that for every pair $a,b$ of real numbers the events $\{X\leq a\}$ and $\{Y\leq b\}$ are independent.

Comment: how would I do it using just the fact that $\{X\le a\},\{Y\le b\}$ are independent to show the singletons are independent, I was thinking an argument related to the original problem but with $\{b-1/n<X\le b\}$ and $ \{d-1/n<Y\le d\}$ but that doesn't work? Borel sets sounds its related to measure theoretic probability, which I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: It works: $P(X=a,Y=b)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(a-\frac1n<X\leq a,b-\frac1n<Y\leq b)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(a-\frac1n<X\leq a)P(b-\frac1n<Y\leq b)=P(X=a)P(X=b)$